# Implementation of CHAP on android client/server application

Tags: android, tcp, ppp

The most common definition of the ppp protocol I have met on the internet is : The Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP)  provides a standard method for transporting multi-protocol datagrams over point-to-point links.  PPP  also defines an extensible Link Control Protocol.

My question : Do we consider a simple client/server application(which transfers images) between two android devices over wi-fi(tcp), a ppp connection.

If yes, how do we implement CHAP on these two devices.

N.B: I do understand what CHAP is and how it works, I just don’t know how I would implement it in this case. Considering also that I don’t use any database or password.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPP is a layer 2 protocol, like Ethernet or Wi-Fi. It's meant for point-to-point *physical* links, and the rest of the TCP/IP stack (IP, TCP, HTTP...) comes on top of it.

So PPP is most certainly not appropriate in your case. Depending on your requirements and setup, you could use HTTP, raw TCP, or possibly a myriad other protocols, though the question of which one to use is way too broad if you don't give us more details.

Comment: Thank you, I don’t mind giving more details. I am writing an application that exchanges images through wifi, so my question is generally on the implementation of CHAP, whether it is possible or not. Which details do you need?

Comment: CHAP is just a pretty simple challenge-response authentication protocol, there's nothing difficult about implementing its equivalent over a raw TCP connection for instance. But you should probably decide what kind of L4 protocol you want to implement, which in turn depends a lot on your requirements (features, whether you're working only on a local LAN or over the Internet, whether you have a client-server or peer-to-peer model, how discovery is done, who initiates transfers, etc.). Also, I don't quite understand why/how you could use CHAP if you don't have passwords...

Comment: (CHAP)it is a requirement which doesn't depend on me, I have to use it. I'm working on a local LAN, client-server, client(which requests the image) is the one that initiates the communication. 

Sorry for bothering a lot. And thanks also for the effort, it's getting clearer.

Comment: CHAP itself is one of the auth protocols for PPP. Since you're not using PPP, you can't use CHAP, but you can reproduce the way it works over any bidirectional medium, or use protocols which provide equivalent functionality (such as HTTP Digest auth). Note however that using CHAP implies storage of passwords in clear text, which is not a good idea.